# Basic Authorization header with JSON

Tags: curl, authorization

Running a curl with Basic Authoirzation header is throwing the following error. I tried giving double quotes and other possibilities, but I still get the same error. Not sure what's wrong here

```
curl -k http://localhost:8080/api/session -H 'Authorization:Basic lkfnnlknvldfbvkjbfjkbkjbfdknbfdlknv==' -H Accept:application/json -X POST
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: lkfnnlknvldfbvkjbfjkbkjbfdknbfdlknv=='; Name or service not known
```

Other tries:

```
curl -k http://localhost:8080/api/session -H 'Authorization:lkfnnlknvldfbvkjbfjkbkjbfdknbfdlknv==' -H Accept:application/json -X POST
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: If you are doing basic auth you need to put the username and pw in it..

Comment: lkfnnlknvldfbvkjbfjkbkjbfdknbfdlknv== is base64 encoded string for the credentials..

Comment: try `curl -u username:password <http link>`

Comment: Thanks, that works with -u and Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded since my creds contained some special characters. However, my intention was not to put in plain text credentials in -u and use the authorization header to use the encoded creds. Is there a way to accomplish that?